# TypeScript React SFC children props type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following stateless functional component defined:

```
import { SFC } from "react";

type ProfileTabContentProps = {
  selected: boolean;
};

const ProfileTabContent: SFC<ProfileTabContentProps> = ({ selected, children }) => selected && children;
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
Type '({ selected, children }: ProfileTabContentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent'.
Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement | null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement | null'.
```

A quick search for related questions all give the same answer, which is very similar to what I've done. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `selected && children` evaluates to `React.ReactNode`, which if you check the typings, is a union type:

```ts
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

However, a `React.SFC` must return a `ReactElement`, it's definition for the function definition is:

```ts
(props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null;
```

I think you've seen the `[truthy] && [render me]` pattern used a lot, but usually inside of a larger TSX component, where a `React.ReactNode` is allowed

You could do this if you want to keep it simple:

```ts
const ProfileTabContent: SFC<ProfileTabContentProps> = ({ selected, children }) => 
  <>{selected && children}</>
```

Which just wraps up your expression inside the shorthand for a `React.ReactFragment`